# Text over image working fine in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, browser, text

I'm trying to add some text over an image. I've set the position of the image to *relative* and the position of the text is *absolute*. It's working completely fine in Firefox but not in Chrome.

All I see in Chrome is an image.

Can anybody help me out in this ?

My code:

```html
<p class="call text-right hidden-xs tel">
    <a href="tel:+18003787566" style="position:absolute; top:300px; left:875px; padding:6px; background-color:#292D30; font-size:26px; padding-left: 100px; padding-right: 127px;">Call: 1-800-378-7566</a>
</p> 
<img src="img/slider/slider01.jpg" alt="" title="" style="margin-top:-28px; position:relative;" />
```

Comment: can you show us your code please?  a fiddle would be great.

Comment: <p class="call text-right hidden-xs tel"><a href="tel:+18003787566" style="position:absolute; top:300px; left:875px; padding:6px; background-color:#292D30; font-size:26px; padding-left: 100px;
padding-right: 127px;">Call: 1-800-378-7566</a></p>

<img src="img/slider/slider01.jpg" alt="" title="" style="margin-top:-28px; position:relative;" />

Comment: Made some copy edits for greater clarity + syntax highlighting of the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

this could help you.
added

```
<p class="call text-right hidden-xs tel">
    <a href="tel:+18003787566" style="position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #292D30;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 127px;
    z-index: 999;">Call: 1-800-378-7566</a>
</p>
```

Added top and left position as well as added z-index.

See the example

http://jsfiddle.net/nanduh/wo2eyhp6/